# Model a 6-digit numeric postal code in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-validation

I would like to define a 6-digit numeric postal code in Django `models.py`.

At first, I tried this;

`postal_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)`

However, postal codes can have leading zeros such as `000157`. PositiveIntegerField is not suitable for it.

If I use `CharField`, the field can accept alphabets which are not valid for postal codes.

How do I define a 6-digit numeric postal code in django models.py?

I am using Django v4.

Comment: Make a [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/#using-validators)?

Comment: why dont you use `CharField` and then limit the user from entering invalid alphabets using regex or other methods in front-end or handle it in `view.py`

Comment: @ImThePeak: *only* validating in the front end is not a good idea: requests can be *forged* and thus circumvent any HTML validation. One should always validate in the backend as well.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i totally agree thats why i mentioned `view` aswell

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a validator, for example by working with a [**`RegexValidator`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.RegexValidator):

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import gettext_lazy as _


class MyModel(models.Model):
    postal_code = models.CharField(
        max_length=6,
        validators=[RegexValidator('^[0-9]{6}$', _('Invalid postal code'))],
    )
```